# Tkinter Treeview used to work when creating striped rows and now it won't work

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a function that retrieves information from a database and then displays the info in a Tkinter Treeview table. When the program used sqlite3, it worked just fine. Now that I've switched to MySQL, it doesn't. I haven't changed the treeview formatting at all.

I've tried changing the placement of the .tag_configure() method, and changing the arguments (background color, tag name). Nothing will make it work again.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class TreeviewTable(ttk.Treeview):
    # Creates a gui_table with given columns.
    def __init__(self, master, columns):
        self.columns = columns
        self.width = int(500 / (len(self.columns)))
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, master, columns=self.columns,
                              show='headings', height=100)
        for i in range(len(self.columns)):
            self.column(self.columns[i], anchor='center', width=self.width)
            self.heading('#{}'.format(str(i+1)), text=self.columns[i],)
        self.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

data = [
    ['Bottles', '1L', 500, '$1.62', '$810.00'],
    ['Bottles', 'Death Wish 1L', 300, '$2.76', '$828.00'],
    ['Labels', 'ALB 1L', 10500, '$0.11', '$1,155.00'],
    ['Capsules', 'ALB 1L', 3400, '$0.08', '$272.00'],
]

window = Tk()
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (500,130))
gui_table = TreeviewTable(window, columns=("Type", "Product", "Amount", "Price", "Total"))
gui_table.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

for (index, row) in enumerate(data, 1): # Created striped rows
    if (index % 2 == 0):
        tag = 'even'
    else:
        tag = 'odd'
    gui_table.insert("", END, values=row, tags=(tag,))
gui_table.tag_configure('even', background='#E8E8E8')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you recently upgraded python? Switching from sqlite3 to mysql absolutely won't change tkinter's behavior.

Comment: Nope, have been on 3.7.3 the whole time. I know that wouldn't make a difference and that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: @BlorbieRandy: Take the output, create a [mcve] using **only** the `for (index, row) ...` loop block and extend the code with the **instantiating part of the `Treeview`. The resulting [mcve] should be runable by others. Remove the `Traceback` this leads into false direction.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you for that link! I've never seen that before, I changed the code once more to allow others to run it easily.

Comment: @BlorbieRandy: As it stands it's working for me. You are using `from tkinter import *` which is **Error prone**. Change to `import tkinter as tk` and prepend **all** `tkinter` with `tk.`, like you are doing with `ttk.`. **BTW**: I recommend to move the `for (index, row) ...` block into a `class methode`, e.g. `TreeviewTable.insert_data(data)`.

Comment: @stovfl thanks for the tip! When I got home I tried running the program on my PC and it worked just fine... Not sure what the issue but hopefully I can find out!